# Botões de um LinearLayout estão ficando gigantes

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou querendo ajustar os botões para que fiquem um embaixo do outro, mas quando tento colocar, eles ficam largos e não como um botão normal. Vejam:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O xml está assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="Propaganda"
        android:text="@string/propaganda" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="BotaoNavegacao"
        android:text="@string/navega_o" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="LoginActivity"
        android:text="@string/login" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Como posso ajustá-los?

Comment: Eles estão um abaixo do outro na foto que você mandou. Como era pra estarem?

Comment: Tem razão Pablo. Me expressei mal. Fiz um ajuste no meu Post. Na verdade eles ficam largos e não como um botão normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu problema é que você está dando `layout_weight` 1 para todos os botões. Isso faz com que todos eles tentem ocupar o espaço completo do pai deles, e acabam ficando com um terço cada. Como o pai deles está ocupando a tela toda, cada um fica com um terço da tela.

Retire as linhas `android:layout_weight="1"` ou mude o `height` do `LinearLayout` para `wrap_content` que seu problema vai embora.

Comment: Perfeito Pablo. Funcionou com as duas dicas que você passou. Muito obrigado.